# Как сделать так что бы значение температуры процессора обновлялось на python

Tags: python, обновление, gpu

```
#Есть код
import GPUtil
gpu = GPUtil.getGPUs()[0]
print(gpu.temperature)
```

Он рисует значение температуры графического ядра
Мне нужно сделать что бы он обновлялся каждые 0.5 сек

Answer (score 0):

Ну, например:

```
import GPUtil
from time import sleep

while True:
    gpu = GPUtil.getGPUs()[0]
    print(f'\r{gpu.temperature}  ', end='', flush=True)
    sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Можете объяснить по подробнее, что за команда Sleep?

Comment: @Lustrator Делает паузу на указанное число секунд